# ¿Cómo guardar un valor de un objeto que esta almacenado en un ArrayList Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

Yo tengo mis productos en una lista y el usuario ingresa por teclado que producto buscar. ¿Cómo hago para comparar ese producto que me pide el usuario con mi lista y devolver ese producto para ultilizarlo despues para hacer la facturación?

Esta es mi **clase principal**:

```
public class Programain {
    public ArrayList<Producto>ListadoProductos= new ArrayList<Producto>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Producto Jugo= new Producto(10, "Jugo ADES");
        Producto Chocolate= new Producto(15, "Chocolate MILKA");
        Producto Cigarrillos= new Producto(20, "Caja Marlboro");
        Producto Bebida= new Producto(50, "Botella COCA-COLA");
        Producto Caramelo= new Producto(5, "Bolsa Caramelos");
        Producto Figuritas= new Producto(100, "Caja FIGURITAS x 300");

        ListadoProductos.add(Jugo);
        ListadoProductos.add(Chocolate);
        ListadoProductos.add(Cigarrillos);
        ListadoProductos.add(Bebida);
        ListadoProductos.add(Caramelo);
        ListadoProductos.add(Figuritas); 
    }

    public void RecorreLista (ArrayList<Producto>ListadoProductos){ 
        for(int i=0; i<ListadoProductos.size();i++){
            System.out.println(ListadoProductos.get(i));
        }
    }

    public Producto DevuelveProducto( ArrayList<Producto>ListadoProductos, String CodigoProducto){
    return null;
    }
}
```

Y esta seria la **clase producto** :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Producto {
double precioUnitario;
String NombreProducto;

public Producto (){
    precioUnitario=0;
    NombreProducto="";
}

public Producto (double precioUnit, String NombreProdu){
     precioUnitario=precioUnit;
     NombreProducto=NombreProdu;
}
public Producto(Producto item){
    precioUnitario= item.precioUnitario;
    NombreProducto=item.NombreProducto;
}
public double getPrecioUnitario() {
    return precioUnitario;
}
public void setPrecioUnitario(double precioUnitario) {
    this.precioUnitario = precioUnitario;
}
public String getNombreProducto() {
    return NombreProducto;
}
public void setNombreProducto(String NombreProducto) {
    this.NombreProducto = NombreProducto;
}

public ArrayList<Producto>ListadoProductos= new ArrayList<Producto>();


 /// hardcodeamos los productos y los agregamos a la lista
```

Comment: falta que agreges la clase  producto

Comment: @Crack81 ahi esta

Answer (score 2):

Podrias recorrer tu `ArrayList` y buscar las coincidencias.

```
public Producto buscarProducto(String codigoProducto){

    for(Producto producto : listadoProductos) {
        if(producto.getCodigoProducto().equals(codigoProducto)) {
            return producto;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Cual es la diferencia con la primera respuesta? Que no es necesario crear un Producto y setearle los valores a este, ya que como estas recorriendo con un `for each` estas obteniendo por cada iteracion un objeto Producto de tu `ArrayList`

Luego haces :

```
Producto productoBuscado = buscarProducto("codigo");
if (productoBuscado == null) {
    //Producto no existe
}else {
    //Producto si existe
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar recorrerla con un forech, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
    public Producto devuelveProducto(ArrayList<Producto>listadoProductos, String codigoProducto){
    Producto nuevo =null;
    for(Producto prod: listadoProductos){
        if(prod.getNombreProducto().equals(codigoProducto)){//Aquí comparas tu código con el de tu lista
            nuevo = new Producto();
            nuevo.setNombreProducto(prod.getNombreProducto());//Aquí setas los valores para devolverlo el objeto tipo Producto
            nuevo.setPrecioUnitario(prod.getPrecioUnitario());//Aquí setas los valores para devolverlo el objeto tipo Producto
        }
        if(prod.getCodigoProducto().equals(codigoProducto.trim())){//Solo puedes ocupar uno o a menos que lo busques por nombre o código
            nuevo = new Producto();
            nuevo.setNombreProducto(prod.getNombreProducto());//Aquí setas los valores para devolverlo el objeto tipo Producto
            nuevo.setPrecioUnitario(prod.getPrecioUnitario());//Aquí setas los valores para devolverlo el objeto tipo Producto
        }
    }if(nuevo != null){
        return nuevo;
    }else{
        //Aquí hacer algo en caso de que no se encuentre el producto
        return null;
    }
}
```

Tu clase Producto

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Producto {


    double precioUnitario;
    String NombreProducto;
    String codigoProducto;

    public Producto (){
        precioUnitario=0;
        NombreProducto="";
    }

    public Producto (double precioUnit, String NombreProdu){
         precioUnitario=precioUnit;
         NombreProducto=NombreProdu;
    }
    public Producto(Producto item){
        precioUnitario= item.precioUnitario;
        NombreProducto=item.NombreProducto;
    }
    public double getPrecioUnitario() {
        return precioUnitario;
    }
    public void setPrecioUnitario(double precioUnitario) {
        this.precioUnitario = precioUnitario;
    }
    public String getNombreProducto() {
        return NombreProducto;
    }
    public void setNombreProducto(String NombreProducto) {
        this.NombreProducto = NombreProducto;
    }

    public ArrayList<Producto>ListadoProductos= new ArrayList<Producto>();

    public String getCodigoProducto() {
        return codigoProducto;
    }

    public void setCodigoProducto(String codigoProducto) {
        this.codigoProducto = codigoProducto;
    }


}
```

Cualquier duda, quedo al pendiente.

Comment: tambien se puede agregar el atributo codigo de producto a la clase producto y utilizar eso? y que el que maneja el programa ponga el codigo de producto y no el nombre, y compare los codigos?

Comment: Claro, dame unos minutos y edito la respuesta con lo que pides

Comment: Para que compares los códigos de tu producto es necesario que lo agregues a tu clase Producto

Answer (score 0):

Primero, si manejas productos y usas termini como `codigoProducto`, deberías tener un código único que identifica los productos como iguales.

En tu código actual usas el nombre del producto como identificador único. Entonces tiene sentido de implementar igualdad para coincidencia de los nombres:

```
public class Producto {

    double precioUnitario;
    String NombreProducto;

    public Producto (){
        precioUnitario=0;
        NombreProducto="";
    }

    public Producto (double precioUnit, String NombreProdu){
         precioUnitario=precioUnit;
         NombreProducto=NombreProdu;
    }
    public Producto(Producto item){
        precioUnitario= item.precioUnitario;
        NombreProducto=item.NombreProducto;
    }
    public double getPrecioUnitario() {
        return precioUnitario;
    }
    public void setPrecioUnitario(double precioUnitario) {
        this.precioUnitario = precioUnitario;
    }
    public String getNombreProducto() {
        return NombreProducto;
    }
    public void setNombreProducto(String NombreProducto) {
        this.NombreProducto = NombreProducto;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        return (o instanceof Producto &&
             ((Producto) o).getNombreProducto().equals(getNombreProducto()));
    }
}
```

Con el override de `equals` se puede usar simplemente:

```
// Comprobar si lista contiene un producto
Producto p = new Producto(precio, nombreProducto);
ListadoProductos.contains(p);

// buscar producto dentro de la lista:
Producto np = ListadoProductos.get(ListadoProductos.indexOf(p));
```

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas Java 8, para este tipo de problemas se utiliza la nueva API Stream. De una forma muy elegante se puede resolver el problema que planteas *en una sola linea de código*:

```
    public Producto buscarProducto(String codigoProducto){
        return listadoProductos.stream().filter(producto -> producto.getCodigoProducto().equals(codigoProducto)).findAny().orElse(null);
    }
```

Donde:

- stream() convierte la lista en un Stream.
- filter() aplica un predicado al Producto que procesa el Stream y lo da por válido si lo evalúa a true. En este caso el predicado es la lambda *producto ->
  producto.getCodigoProducto().equals(codigoProducto)* que simplemente comprueba la igualdad.
- finAny() hace que termine el procesamiento del stream en cuanto encuentre un elemento, devolviendo un Optional. En este caso un Optional que contendrá el primer producto que cumple el filter anterior o Optinal.empty.
- orElse() : en caso de que el Optional devuelto por findAny este vacío hace que devuelva lo que le pasamos en el parámetro del método, en este caso he elegido un nulo, para ilustrar la funcionalidad, pero perfectamente podría ser un Producto por defecto (por ejemplo new Producto(-1,"No encontrado"))

Realmente recomiendo aprender a trabajar con este API, ya que las soluciones que aporta son muchísimo más concisas que ñas tradicionales basadas en bucles.